# kubectl doesn't load the new endpoint to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubectl, amazon-eks

When i run **kubectl get svc** i have the error `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup DB3E0792B37BE7363D42AF594F4C72AB.gr7.eu-centrale-1.xx.`

I update my **~/.kube/config** to add the new endpoint  `https://6AF7819922F51E229C9B408FE5DXXXXXXX.gr7.eu-central-1`.

However It seems **kubectl** doesn't load the new endpoint.
Because if i run again **kubectl get svc** he try to connect to same previous endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple cluster contexts. Use kubectl to edit this and target the context you wish to edit.

```
$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
  certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
  server: https://10.0.0.10:6443
name: default
.....
```

To update the endpoint to from 10.0.0.10 to 192.168.0.1:

```
$ kubectl config set-cluster default --server=https://192.168.0.1
Cluster "default" set.
```

Validate the update is correct:

```
$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
  certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
  server: https://192.168.0.1
name: default
....
```

Also ensure you have switched to the correct context by (in this case "default") context:

```
$ kubectl config use-context default
Switched to context "default".
```

Comment: thanks for your help ! i tried but unfortunately nothing change .

Comment: Have you validated the endpoint its hitting by running `kubectl get nodes --v=10`

Comment: $**sudo kubectl config set-cluster default --server=https://6AF7819922F51E229C
9B408FE5.gr7.eu-central-1.eks.amazonaws.com**
Cluster "default" set.
$sudo kubectl get svc
`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup DB3E0792B37BE7363D42AF52AB.gr7.eu-central-1.eks.amazonaws.com on 192.168.43.X:53: no such host`